# convergence of the series $\sum^\infty_{k=1}kx^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series
$$\sum^\infty_{k=1}kx^k$$converges to $$\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$$
Could anyone give me a hint on how this convergence can be proven? I am especially puzzled as the $k$ on the left seems to disappear completely in the process of convergence.

Comment: The $(1-z)^2$ that you see in the right, take it multiplying to the left and expand. All terms cancel except $z$.

Comment: Let $S_n=\sum^n_{k=1}kx^k$ and look at $$S_{n+1}-xS_n$$then take $n\rightarrow\infty$ (under some restriction on the value of $x$, so the limit is finite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty kz^k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(k+1)z^k-z^k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(k+1)z^k-\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k=\frac{d}{dz}\left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^{k+1} \right]-\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k$$

Even easier: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty kz^k=z\sum_{k=1}^\infty kz^{k-1}=z\frac{d}{dz}\left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k \right]$$

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful. But I have 2 questions: is this true for any z? And I still don't quite see how I get from here to the convergence.

Comment: @Jonas Only true for $\lvert z\rvert <1$.

Comment: We have $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$$ which evaluates to $\frac{1}{1-z}$ when $|z|<1\implies z^n\to 0$ (as vitamin d notes). Both of the sums at the end can be put in terms of the geometric series above.

Comment: @Jonas $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{k+1}=z\sum_{k=0}^\infty  z^k=?$$

Comment: This clearly evaluates to z/(1-z).

Comment: Exactly. Can you do the other one?

Comment: If I try to evaluate the above-mentioned differential, I have a problem, cause in order to bring it to the form needed (starting with k=0) I would have to divide the term by z^2 and then the differentiation is no longer straightforward, as I would have to use the quotient rule.

Comment: You should have the sum evaluate to $\frac{z^2}{1-z}$ and then use the quotient rule to differentiate it.

Comment: Thank you! Now I received the desired result. And thank you also for being so patient and explaining the details!